# Zero size arrays in gcc c++ compiler

Tags: c++, arrays

What will be the output of following c++ code snippet.

How we can assign a value to a variable which occupies no memory (0 bytes).Also doing pointer arithmetic gives false results(implied)

```cpp
int main()
{
    int arr[0];
     arr[1]=1;
    cout<<arr[1]<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
    int *p=arr;
    int *q=p+1;
    cout<<p-q;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample execution ==> https://code.hackerearth.com/f8d7b1G

Comment: Considering that zero-sized arrays aren't allowed by standard C++ the whole question is moot.

Comment: A relevant part is [dcl.array/1]: [`N` shall be greater than zero](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1.sentence-3)

Comment: While there are zero-sized `std::tuple`s and `std::array`s, there are no zero-sized C style arrays.

Comment: Zero-size arrays are a [compiler extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). Try compiling with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Even if zero-sized arrays are compiler extension of your compiler the code `int arr[0]; arr[1]=1;` causes undefined behavior and the run of your program can't be predicted. The compiler is allowed to generate machine code that could  do anything like formatting your harddrive or ordering a pizza. _"How we can assign a value to a variable which occupies no memory (0 bytes)?"_ You can't.

Comment: regarding the pointer arithmetic: its undefined beahviour, just as with a non-zero sized array when you go out of bounds

Comment: Is it reasonable to close "what is the result of my UB" questions as opinion-based? There must be a better way than just saying it is UB and hoping the author deletes it ...

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, your code causes undefined behaviour.

Let's see how it works.

```
int a, b;
int c[2];
```

This will look like (imagine this as a stack inside the function "main"):

```
/***


+--------------------+  <- 0xXXXXXXXX (initial address)
|         a          |
+--------------------+  <- 0xXXXXXXXX + sizeof int (initial address + size of variable a) == &a
|         b          |
+--------------------+  <- ... + sizeof int (... + size of variable b) == &b
|        c[1]        |
+--------------------+ 
|        c[0]        |
+--------------------+  <- ... + number of bytes that are being allocated by the array (it's the pointer to the array)
                       == c or &c[0]
+--------------------+
|    c (pointer)     |
+--------------------+

// remember that compiler don't have to allocate it like this, it's just an example

***/
```

When you are trying to do something like this:

```
c[0] = 1;
```

it's being the same as:

```
*(c + 0) = 1;
```

because variable "c" contains the pointer to the array. It also explains why does a compiler allocate it reversely on the stack (because if we want to access a specific member of an array, we have to write something i did a little bit upper — `*(c + N) = 1;`, because **STACK GROWS DOWN**. If you still confused with it, write it in the comments below, i'll explain.

So, if you write something like this

```
int a, b;
int c[0];
```

It looks like:

```
/***


+--------------------+  <- 0xXXXXXXXX (initial address)
|         a          |
+--------------------+  <- 0xXXXXXXXX + sizeof int (initial address + size of variable a) == &a
|         b          |
+--------------------+  <- ... + sizeof int AND 
                               + number of bytes that are being allocated by the 
                                 array. 
                                 When the number of bytes is ZERO,
                                 it equals to the address of the variable "b",
                                 because &b + 0 == &b
+--------------------+
|    c (pointer)     |
+--------------------+

***/
```

So, we could say that what you are doing is:

```
*(&b + 1) = 1;
```

**THIS IS VERY UNSAFE**. Imagine there was no variable "b" or variable "a", you would just be managing something you shouldn't. 
That's why zero-sized arrays are not allowed in C++ standart.